# Wierd textures from importing glTF file from blender into godot - need help fixing

Tags: modeling, materials, objects, export, gltf

I exported my model shown on the first picture into a glTF binary file, but when I imported it into godot the materials got swapped into weird places.

[image: What it should look like]

[image: What it looks like]

Are there any fixes for this problem?

Sorry if this is an easy fix question.

Comment: Are you using UV coordinates for those textures, or something else?  Are there multiple sets of UVs?  Try exporting just a single set of UV coordinates.

Comment: @emackey I am new to texturing so I'm not sure what UV coordinates are. But I just added materials to each mesh and haven't dealt with any of the UV part. It also seems like its only the areas with the same materials (duplicated using Alt+D) that are produced wrongly after importing. I have also opened it in window's in-built 3d viewer and it seems to be working fine, so would this still be a problem with exporting from blender?

Comment: UV coordinates are the way to control where textures get applied in glTF, so I would recommend reading up on them a bit.  There's a good intro to UV mapping in the Blender Manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/editors/uv/introduction.html